# How to load a module and navigate to the module? Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have two modules: `ModuleLogging` and `ModuleItems`.
My `Shell` has declaration:

```
<Grid>
   <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ContentControl  DockPanel.Dock="Top" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.TheUpperRegion}" Margin="5" />
    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.TheBottomRegion}" Margin="5"/>                     
   </DockPanel>

    <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.TheWholeRegion}" Margin="5"  />
</Grid>
```

The `ModuleLogging` is loaded at first. Then if user is authenticated, I would like to load `ModuleItems`.
As I understood correctly, I should instantiate

My bootstrapper class:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
   ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
   catalog.AddModule(typeof(ModuleLogging));
   //I've not added ModuleItems as I want to check whether the user is authorized
   return catalog;
}
```

What I've tried to call `ModuleItems` from `ModuleLogging`:

```
Uri viewNav = new Uri("ModuleItems", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheUpperRegion, viewNav);
regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheBottomRegion, viewNav);
```

But my `LoggingView` of `ModuleLogging` is not replaced by the `ToolBarView` of `ModuleItems` and `DockingView` of `ModuleItems`. I just see  `System.Object` and  `System.Object` respectively in ContentControls instead of controls as `LoggingView` is transparent.

Yeah, I know that there is no object in memory such as `ModuleItems` .

How to load module on demand and navigate to the views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The greatest [Magnus Montin](http://blog.magnusmontin.net) helps me to solve the [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6bfe12f5-2493-4275-968d-ea082d980e49/how-to-load-a-module-and-navigate-to-the-module-prism?forum=wpf):

This code is located at `LoggingViewmodel` of `ModuleLogging`:

```
private void DoLogin(object obj)
    {
        ShowAnotherView = false;
        if (UserName == "1" && UserPassword == "1")
        {                
            container.RegisterType<Object, TheUpperControl>("ModuleItems");
            Uri viewNav = new Uri("ModuleItems", UriKind.Relative);
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheUpperRegion, viewNav);
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.TheBottomRegion, viewNav);
            LoadTheOtherModule(); //load the other module
            var loginView = regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Views.ElementAt(0);
            regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TheWholeRegion].Remove(loginView); //remove the login view
            //MessageBox.Show("");    
        }
        else
            ShowPromptingMessage = true;
    }

    private void LoadTheOtherModule()
    {
        Type moduleType = typeof(ModuleItems.ModuleItemsModule);
        ModuleInfo mi = new ModuleInfo()
        {
            ModuleName = moduleType.Name,
            ModuleType = moduleType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
        };
        IModuleCatalog catalog = container.Resolve<IModuleCatalog>();
        catalog.AddModule(mi);
        catalog.Initialize();

        IModuleManager moduleManager = container.Resolve<IModuleManager>();
        moduleManager.LoadModule(moduleType.Name); //run Initialize() of the other module
    }
```

It works like a charm!:)

Comment: It's practically the same that I suggested. Eh never mind, I'm glad your problem is solved.

Comment: @pangabiMC  Thanks a lot you for your effort! :) I upvoted on your reply. But I needed more explanatory answer where I should put code.

Answer (score 8):

You may need to sort these to get it working properly:

- Adding your module to the catalog
- Loading the module on demand
- Registering your view (or viewmodel) that will be shown in the region
- Requesting the navigation to your view

Let's see in order

### Adding your module to the catalog

I don't see any reason for not adding your module to the catalog, however what you probably don't want till after the authentication, is initialising the module. To get your Module initialised on demand you can add it to the catalog with the flag `OnDemand`:

> The module will be initialized when requested, and not automatically
>   on application start-up.

In your bootstrapper:

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    Type ModuleItemsType = typeof(ModuleItems);
    ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo()
    {
        ModuleName = ModuleItemsType.Name,
        ModuleType = ModuleItemsType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
        InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand
    });
```

### Loading the module on demand

Then after the authentication succeeded you can initialise your module:

```
private void OnAuthenticated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.moduleManager.LoadModule("ModuleItems");    
}
```

where `moduleManager` is an instance of `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleManager` (preferably injected to your class constructor)

### Registering your view

You also need to register your view (or viewmodel if you're using viewmodel-first) you want to navigate to in the container. The best place to do this is probably the Initialisation of your module ModuleItems, just make sure the container is injected in its constructor:

```
public ModuleItems(IUnityContainer container)
{
    _container = container;
}

public void Initialize()
{
    _container.RegisterType<object, ToolBarView>(typeof(ToolBarView).FullName);
    _container.RegisterType<object, DockingView>(typeof(DockingView).FullName);
    // rest of initialisation
}
```

Note that in order to make the RequestNavigate to work you must register your view as an object and also you must provide its full name as the name parameter.

Also using the Module as the navigation target (like you did here: `Uri viewNav = new Uri("ModuleItems", UriKind.Relative);` is probably not the best idea. The module object is usually just a temporary object which is thrown away by default once your module is initialised.

### Requesting the navigation

Then finally, once your module is loaded you can request the navigation. You can use the above mentioned moduleManager to hook to the `LoadModuleCompleted` event:

```
this.moduleManager.LoadModuleCompleted += (s, e)
    {
        if (e.ModuleInfo.ModuleName == "ModuleItems")
        {
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(
                RegionNames.TheUpperRegion,
                typeof(ToolBarView).FullName), 
                result => 
                { 
                   // you can check here if the navigation was successful
                });

            regionManager.RequestNavigate(
                RegionNames.TheBottomRegion,
                typeof(DockingView).FullName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where should I subscribe to an event moduleManager. LoadModuleCompleted? At the method  OnAuthenticated(object sender, EventArgs args) or at constructor of ModuleItems?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as it's subscribed to before the LoadModule is called. So yes, if you call OnAuthenticated when the logging finished and put the subscription before the LoadModule it should be fine.

Comment: There is a nice article on MSDN by the way about this topic, also with examples in MEF if you're using that instead of Unity: [Modular Application Development Using Prism Library 5.0 for WPF - Loading Modules on Demand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec28)

Comment: but I cannot use ToolBarView at ModuleLogging cause it is tight couple. I've tried to subsribe at ModuleItems, but it is not working

Comment: Well, that's true, but there are several ways around it. Technically you don't need the ToolBarView to navigate to it, you only need its name. But that's still too much coupling to my taste. Perhaps better if you simply call RequestNavigate at the end of `ModuleItems.Initialise` method. 
Or a third and perhaps the cleanest option would be to fire an event through the EventAggregator when the module is loaded and subscribe to that event by some view controller singleton object in ModuleItems. (note that IModule is a temporary object, with weak events it won't work if you subscribe there)